# How to finish this Ender's Game script in Processing?

Tags: processing

```java
   /* Draw a laser beam from the start point in the direction of the end point
 but have it stop if it bumps into a rock.*/

int laserColor = color(255, 0, 0);
int rockColor = color(0, 255, 0) ;
int startX = (1);
int startY = (1);
int laserX = (10);
int laserY = (20);
int laserDX = (30);
int laserDY = (40);

float r = 100;
float g = 150;
float b = 200;
float a = 200;
float f = 100;

float diam = 20;
float dim = 70;

float x = 100;
float y = 100;
float z = 20;
int t = 100;
int s = 100;
int w = 60;
int h = 60;
int eyeSize = 16;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  background(239, 276, 238);
}

void draw() {
  drawPlayer();
  drawRocks();
  drawWall();
  drawBeam();
  background(255);
  if (mousePressed) {
    a--;
    fill(0);
    text("Score" + a, 325, 10);
  }
  {
  void drawPlayer(){
      // Draw player's head
  fill(255);
  ellipse(x,y,w,h);

  // Draw player's eyes
  fill(0);
  ellipse(x-w/3+1,y,eyeSize,eyeSize*2);
  ellipse(x+w/3-1,y,eyeSize,eyeSize*2);
  }

  void drawRocks(){
    //draw rocks
    fill(255);
    ellipse(x, y+(x/2), diam, diam);

    fill(255);
    ellipse(x+(3*x), y+(.5*x), diam, diam);

    fill (255);
    ellipse(x+(2*x), y+y, diam, diam);

    fill(255);
    ellipse(x+y, y+y, diam, diam);
  }

  void drawWall(){
    // draw the wall 
  stroke(0);
    fill(f, w, f, a);
  rect(x+(1.5*x), (y-(.05*z)), dim, diam);
  }

  void drawBeam(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
    float laserX, laserY, laserDX, laserDY;
    stroke(156, 255, 0);
    strokeWeight(5);
    float distance = dist(endX, endY, startX, startY);
  }
  }
}
{

// expand the reach of the beam about 1 pixel per loop iteration
// so it doesn't skip over anything

laserDX = (endX-startX)/distance;
laserDY = (endY-startY)/distance;

// make sure both laserDX and laserDY aren't zero or the loop will never end
if (laserDX == 0 && laserDY == 0) {
  return; // don't draw anything
}

// lx,ly track where the beam will end
float lx = startX; 
float ly = startY;

// move along in the direction of the beam until you hit the edge or an object
while (get((int)lx, (int)ly) != rockColor && lx > 0 && lx < width && ly > 0 && ly < height) {
  lx = lx + laserDX;
  ly = ly + laserDY;
}
// found the end of the laser beam - draw it
line(startX, startY, lx, ly);
}
```

For some reason this comes up as an error. I don't know why the functions aren't working and I also don't know how to declare the laser and whatnot.  I have to do more with this code but right now I'm just trying to clean up what I have because I know this is the basic outline of what I have to do.

Comment: Is this C#? You should add tag(s) related to the language you are using

Comment: @jhhoff02 It's Processing. Please notice the [tag:processing] tag.

Comment: Thank you Kevin :)

Comment: yes, processing :)

Comment: I also forgot to add the player's head, sorry about that. I'm not sure how to edit it yet but here it is

Comment: I added it but I probably put it in incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's designed for more specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. The thing about code is that there are a million ways to do any one thing, and which approach you take depends more on you than it does on us. So it can be really hard to help if you don't have a specific question. That being said, I'll try to help in a general sense:

First off, your code doesn't compile. Your `drawRocks()` and `drawBeam()` functions are defined **inside** your `draw()` function, which is not valid syntax. You can't have functions inside other functions like that. In other words, **this is wrong:**

```
void draw(){

   void drawRocks(){
      //draw rocks
   }

   void drawBeam(){
      //draw beam
   }
}
```

You need to define all of your functions at the same level, like this:

```
void draw(){
   drawRocks();
   drawBeam();
}

void drawRocks(){
   //draw rocks
}

void drawBeam(){
   //draw beam
}
```

Notice how I'm defining the functions at the same level, and then calling the `drawRocks()` and `drawBeam()` functions from the `draw()` function.

But simply moving the `drawBeam()` function to outside the `draw()` function won't work, since you have variables inside that function that you're trying to use outside of it. That doesn't make a ton of sense.

**The best advice I can give you is to start smaller.** You seem to be biting off more than you should be chewing right now, which is a very common mistake that novices (and non-novices) make.

Start over with a more basic sketch that just does **one thing**. Just get a single circle moving around the screen. Get that working perfectly before you move on. Then make it so the circle bounces off the edges of the screen. Then make it so the circle bounces off a square in the middle of the screen.

Work your way up in small steps like that. **Start small.** Smaller than you think is interesting. Don't try to take on your whole game at once. Work in small example programs, that way if you get stuck you'll be able to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a specific question. Good luck.

Comment: okay thanks so much

Comment: Great answer, Kevin - whilst this Q was correctly closed, it is nice to see posts that give general beginner's advice, even if the Q/A won't survive in the long term.